# Not sure what I missed on this suggested edit review

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7719571

I'm not sure what I missed on this edit review. I was the only reject, and the edit only put the *still syntactically invalid* Java code and changed a couple of words.

Should I have approved the edit because it was intended to improved the semantics of the question (i.e. it was not a quote but code blocks), or done as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing is that the edit improved the *readability* of the question, which was its main goal.  It shouldn't have been to fix any of the syntax issues.

The edit looks pretty good to me; I'd have approved it as well, then commented on the syntactically invalid `extends` bit afterward.

It's alright if you don't agree with an edit, but I'd encourage you to look past syntax and see if the question itself has improved.  If it has, then there's not much reason to reject it.

Comment: I've in the past skipped suggested edits for languages / topics I'm not familiar with. Is that proper to do in your opinion?

Comment: [If you're not sure, skip it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/1079354) There is no shame in that at all.